# namespace export from index.js

Tags: es6-modules

My `index.js` in a given directory exports several things like this:

```
export * from 'fileOne';
export * from 'fileTwo';
export * from 'fileThree';
```

I want to name space the stuff from file4, something like this:

```
export { default as mockStuff } from 'file4';
```

OR

```
export { * as mockStuff } from 'file4'
```

I've even tried (and various combinations):

```
import * as mockStuff from 'file4';
export mockStuff
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
import * as mockStuff from "./file4";
export { mockStuff };
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks! (edit: well, almost, it's `import * as mockStuff`)

Comment: The posted answer only works with a _default_ export.