# How can I export * as namespace in Babel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am working on code that is a mixture of JS and TS, using TypeScript 3.8. I wrote the following line:

```js
export * as Easing from './easing';
```

Which should be [fair game](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#export--as-ns-syntax) in TypeScript 3.8. However, I am compiling using Webpack, and I am not using `ts-loader`, only `babel-loader` with the TypeScript preset, and it seems like Babel does not support this syntax. I'm getting this error:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/index.ts
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
> SyntaxError: /home/laptou/projects/my-project/src/index.ts: Unexpected export specifier type
>  30 |     default as Clock, addUpdateListener, after, chain, clock, infinite, tween
>  31 | } from './clock';
>  32 | export * as Easing from './easing';
>     |        ^^^^^^^^^^^
>  33 | export type { Tween, TweenOptions, TweenStatus } from './tween';
>  34 | export { default as InterpolateTween } from './tween/interpolate'
> ```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've asked this question before here: [namespace export from index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446113/namespace-export-from-index-js)

```
import * as Easing from './easing';
export { Easing }
```

Comment: I guess that does the trick. I was looking for a Babel extension/option that would simply add the syntax, since it is already supported by TypeScript. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you're using babel, you MAY have to add a plugin, such as `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
// ./some/someFile.ts

export function util1 () {
...
}

export function util2 () {
...
}

export function util3 () {
...
}
```

An on your index or any file you import yow functions

```js
// ./some/index.ts

export * as utils from "./someFile";
```

If by any means you get some problems.

Change your index.ts to:

```js
import * as utils from "./someFile";

export { utils };
```

or we could used the old but always trusted default form:

```js
// ./some/someFile.ts

function util1 () {
...
}

function util2 () {
...
}

function util3 () {
...
}

export default {
   util1,
   util2,
   util3
}
```

at the index

```js
import utils from "./someFile";
export { utils };

// or
export { default as utils } from "./someFile";
```

Comment: Just adding that on older versions of Babel, `export * from "..."` is not supported, you would need to add a plugin, such as `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`